# How to create server side validation in fat free framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

how to check validate format for email and password and confirm password?
how to return errors for required field.

here is my fat free function-

```
    $f3->route('GET|POST /addstep',
    function($f3) use ($db){
        $idss = $f3->get('SESSION.id');
        //print_r($_SESSION);die; 
        $data = json_decode($f3['BODY']);

        $title = $data->title;
        $first_name = $data->first_name;
        $middle_initial = $data->middle_initial;
        $last_name =  $data->last_name;
        $email = $data->email;
        $password = $data->password;
        $confirm_password = $data->confirm_password;
        $tax_id = $data->tax_id;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little plugin that might be able to help you.

Check the [Fat Free Framework Validator](https://github.com/acemureithi/f3-validate)

Little example:

```
$data = $f3->get('POST')
$valid = Validate::is_valid($data, array(
    'username' => 'required|alpha_numeric',
    'password' => 'required|max_len,100|min_len,6'
));

if($valid === true) {
    // continue
} else {
    print_r($valid); // the invalid items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [f3-validator](https://github.com/AnandPilania/f3-validator), its also supports model based validation.

For example:

```
$rules = array(
  'email' => 'email|unique:users', // uniqueness of email in users table
  'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:3|max:20', // confirm password
  'name' => 'required|between:6,12'
);
```

Initiating:

```
$validator = Validator::instance()->validate($data, $rules);
```

OR

```
$validator = new Validator($data, $rules);
$validator->validate();
```

Checking:

```
$validator->passed(); // return true|false
```

Getting errors:

```
$validator->errors();
```